# using classes in jenkins job dsl

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Hi all I have a problem and I can't seem to figure it out.

So I'm creating some helper classes for my dsl to use, but it just does not seem to execute any method within these classes.

I have created a job with the following dsl in it:

```
class TestIt {
  def static helloStatic() {
    println "[STATIC] - Hello"
  }

  def hello() {
    println "[NORMAL] - Hello"
  }
}

def runIt() {
  println "Starting test"
  println "-------------"
  TestIt _test = new TestIt()
  _test.hello();
  TestIt.helloStatic();
  println "-------------"
  println "Done"
}

runIt();
TestIt.helloStatic();
```

When I run this job with jenkins it does not display/execute either the static or normal method. Do I need to somehow inject the class in the current running context or do something else?

Also note that if I run this exact same script from the command line, using a github version of the job dsl plugin and gradle, then the script does call the methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using println in scripts (in your example, in the `runIt` function), Groovy sends the call to a `out` variable defined in the script's binding or to `System.out.println` if the variable is not set. The Job DSL plugin sets this variable so that the output goes to the build log.

When using println in classes (in your example, the `TestIt` class), `System.out.println` will be called. So the output is send to stdout. And depending on how you started Jenkins, stdout is e.g. logged the console or `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`.

To send the output from classes to the build log, you need to pass the `out` variable to your class:

```
class TestIt {
  def out

  def static helloStatic(def out) {
    out.println "[STATIC] - Hello"
  }

  def hello() {
    out.println "[NORMAL] - Hello"
  }
}

def runIt() {
  println "Starting test"
  println "-------------"
  TestIt _test = new TestIt(out: out)
  _test.hello();
  TestIt.helloStatic(out);
  println "-------------"
  println "Done"
}

runIt();
TestIt.helloStatic(out);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed to get going again. Documentation is lacking for someone with no knowledge of groovy (i'm primarily into c++). I will see if i can add this to the wiki on github for other users.

Comment: The next Job DSL release will have a section about logging in the docs, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/512